# Is my HTTP-Server able to detect the connection speed of the Client?

Tags: php, performance, http, download

Is it possible to measure the download speed of the Client with a script running on the server (HTTP)?

How can I interpret the logged time of the following PHP-Script?

```
header("Content-Type: plain/text");
header("Content-Disposition: Attachment; filename=test.txt");
header('Content-Length: ' . 5);
header("Pragma: no-cache");

$start=microtime(true); // Start 
echo "abcde";

log(microtime(true)-$start); // End + log
exit();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You script would give you the execution time of the script on the server. PHP is parsed server side and transmitted to the client. Therefore, the server would calculate the time to prepare "abcde" to transmit to the client.

If you want to measure link speed, you're going to need client side code to do this. Unfortunately, I don't have any code I can suggest

Comment: To be sure - If the server sends much more data than 'abcde' I think there are some protocol layers that will split the data into tokens. Can I say that in the worst case the server has sent all tokens and the client hasn't received any of them at that time?

Comment: But how would you measure whether the data had been received by the client machine? PHP is *fully* server based. One way you *might* be able to do it is to store the microtime of transmission start, pump a page to the client and then have the page redirect to another script which will store the retrieval time of that script. Link it all to the session ID, take one from the other and you have a sort-of transmission time. Rough as hell but possible without delving into client-side stuff.

Comment: The APC lib can help you to measure the speed when uploading a file to a server from a client machine.